# Ошибка 'NoneType' object is not callable при GET запросе в DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Всем привет! Уже создал вьюсет для отображения списка элементов из бд, добавления, обновления и удаления элемента. Возникла проблема при создании вьюсета для отображения детальной информации по элементу.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('tasks', views.TaskViewset.as_view(
        {
            'get':'list',
            'post':'add',
            'put':'update',
            'delete':'delete'
        }
    )),
    path('tasks/<int:pk>', views.TaskDetailViewset.as_view(
        {
            'get':'detail'
        }
    ))
]
```

views.py:

```
class TaskViewset(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def list(self, request):
        tasks = models.Task.objects.all()

        if tasks:
            return Response(data=serializers.TaskSerializer(tasks, many=True).data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response('No tasks found', status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)


    def add(self, request):
        data = request.data
        serializer = serializers.TaskSerializer(data=data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(data=data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    
    def update(self, request):
        data = request.data
        task = models.Task.objects.get(id=data.get('id'))
        serializer = serializers.TaskSerializer(task, data=data)
        
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(data=serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


    def delete(self, request):
        data = request.data
        models.Task.objects.get(id=data.get('id')).delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)


class TaskDetailViewset(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def detail(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #data = request.query_params
        task = models.Task.objects.get(id=kwargs['pk'])
        serializer = serializers.TaskSerializer(task)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            return Response(data=serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

При попытке обратиться к http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/tasks/1 получаю следующую ошибку:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/tasks/1

Django Version: 4.1.2
Python Version: 3.10.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'todo']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aleksandr/Documents/projects/todoist/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/aleksandr/Documents/projects/todoist/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/aleksandr/Documents/projects/todoist/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/aleksandr/Documents/projects/todoist/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 125, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/aleksandr/Documents/projects/todoist/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/aleksandr/Documents/projects/todoist/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/aleksandr/Documents/projects/todoist/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/Users/aleksandr/Documents/projects/todoist/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /api/v1/tasks/1
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

В интерактивном дебагере нашел вот такую штуку:
[handler None, очевидно в этом проблема. Почему так я не понимаю.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwlAG.png)

Comment: task = models.Task.objects.get(id=kwargs['pk']) что-то я не припомню такой синтаксис. у тебя модель если Task, то и вызывай ее task = Task.objects.get(id=kwargs['pk'])

Comment: @JopaBoga я просто импортировал модуль, а не модель. Импортировал бы модель, то так бы и писал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задавал этот вопрос также на англоязычном stackoverflow, там же нашли ответ. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74023402/django-rest-framework-nonetype-object-is-not-callable

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)